# Expression tree library ignores short-circuit evaluation concept

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Please, take a look at following proof of concept:

```
private class Model
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public bool NonEmpty() { return Data.Length > 0; }
}

private static Func<Model, bool> Compile()
{
    var type = typeof(Model);
    var expr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Model));

    var subarg1 = Expression.Property(expr, type.GetProperty("Data"));
    var subarg2 = Expression.Constant(null);
    var arg1 = Expression.NotEqual(subarg1, subarg2);

    var arg2 = Expression.Call(expr, type.GetMethod("NonEmpty"));

    var tree = Expression.And(arg1, arg2); // Data != null && NonEmpty()
    var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Model, bool>>(tree, expr).Compile();
    return func;
}

var model = new Model {Data = null};
var standardTest = model.Data != null && model.NonEmpty(); // returns false
var exprTreeTest = Compile().Invoke(model); // throws null ref exception
```

Because the first operand evaluates to false, the result of the AND operation is false no matter what the value of second one may be. That's why the second operand shouldn't be computed. While C# compiler does it correctly, expression library does not.

How to fix my code to respect the short-circuit evaluation?

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of headaches and use a lambda to create such an expression instead of doing it all as you have done.  It's faster, easier, and would have resulted in the correct expression being generated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Expression.And` represents the non-short circuiting AND operator (`&`).

`Expression.AndAlso` represents the short circuiting AND operator (`&&`).